# Check if size of electron window changed

Tags: electron

I wanna have a listener ( or something ) to check if the size of the window changes, do something ( like re-rendering entire view page ).

How should I do this?

Comment: Could you tell me if my answer worked or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `resize` event like so:

```
window.on('resize', function () {
    var size   = window.getSize();
    var width  = size[0];
    var height = size[1];
    console.log("width: " + width);
    console.log("height: " + height);
});
```

[Docs here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#event-resize)

Comment: I did exactly what you have shown but it does nothing in my app. It logs nothing anywhere.

Comment: @VirejDasani Interesting, perhaps you can ask another StackOverflow question with more detail about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the above answer. You have to set the `resize` event on the main window you created. Further, if you want to access the width or height inside another file, you can emit another event and pass the width or height as a parameter. Here is a simple example of what I have done.

```
mainWindow.on("resize", function () {
    var size = mainWindow.getSize();
    var width = size[0];
    var height = size[1];
    mainWindow.webContents.send("resized", height);
    console.log(size);
    console.log("width: " + width);
    console.log("height: " + height);
  });
```